# UX of editing / adding Favorite tags at least in Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm a member of the [Charcoal](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/questions) <s>Channel</s> Team. I don't have any *Charcoal Favorite tags* yet. This is what I see, an edit link and an Add a favorite tag link:

[image]

Clicking *Add a favorite tag* brings me here:

[image]

If I click *edit*, it shows me this:

[image]

Clicking the suddenly appeared *Add an ignored tag* does nothing.

I'm not sure what was intended but it looks like there are is a mix now of links to click that are at best inconsistent.

Not being an UX developer but I think or the *edit* link should be enough (so the *Add a favorite tag* link can go) or the *edit* link should go when I don't have favorite or ignored tags, in which case the *Add an ignored tag* should be added.

I'm fine to have a single link called *Edit* to change both tag sets once I have set  favorite or ignored tags.

Comment: I recall seeing something vaguely similar in the desktop view on one of the regular sites recently (I think I was on Super User at the time). Are you sure this is specific to Teams and/or mobile? (I too am on mobile at the mo...)

Comment: @tripleee I'll have to check, but on SO proper the UX seems to be different anyway

Comment: @tripleee repro-ed on Super User as well.

Comment: Should this be migrated to [meta.se] then?

Comment: @tripleee I can report bugs on any site meta. If some SE dev wants it there, I assume they migrate.

Comment: @rene I can't repro this on Superuser. Can you? When I click "edit" I don't get the super confusing "Add an ignored tag" link. The UX for this is getting an overhaul. It will show up for Teams users today (still a WIP). Next month it will get updated everywhere.

Comment: @JoeFriend No, something has changed as I can't repro on Super User anymore.