# Hide questions in your ignored tags is ignored

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, profile-page

I take part in the Teams beta. Yesterday a lot of bugs and other reports related to teams were pushed to production, including one of my own regarding [favorite and ignored tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364424/ux-of-editing-adding-favorite-tags-at-least-in-teams).

It looks like that, after these changes, my setting for *Hide questions in your ignored tags* in my [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) is no longer honored. My setting:

[image: prefference setting]

And this is what [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) looks like for me:

[image: grayed out, not ignored]

IIRC this functionality relies on a client-side script, but there are no errors in my console, so it isn't a client-side script failure. And it isn't limited to my Chrome browser either, as I repro-ed this behavior in Edge as well.

It appears that the function [`hideIgnored()`](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=8981fe7b960e) will never return true:

```js
var hideIgnored = function () {
    if ($("#hideIgnoredTrue").is(":checked"))
        return true;
    if ($("#hideIgnoredFalse").is(":checked"))
        return false;
    return $("#hideIgnored").is(":checked");
};
```

as the DOM input element with the ID hideIgnored, hideIgnoredTrue, hideIgnoredFalse are no longer present. I suspect this is due to the newly-introduced tag editor. On [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) there is a radio button with that ID present in the resulting DOM.

Can this functionality that worked up to Thursday SE-day-wise be restored in working order please? I don't want to subject my eyes and brain to PHP (or Python for that matter).

Comment: This is what questions in ignored tags look like for people who aren't participating in the Teams beta... is it supposed to look different for people who *are* participating?

Comment: @TylerH I don't think so, I have my ignored tags hidden since the moment I started using the feature (6 to 8 years ago) and that worked ever since. I only know that my overall UI on main is different since I joined teams so I want to be explicit about that. I had other UI bugs on main related to teams.

Comment: Oh I see, I was totally missing the fact that you had selected "Hide" rather than "Grey out"; I didn't even realize there was a Hide feature...

Comment: Ignoreception. **baaaaam**

Comment: This is my fault.  I'll look at it today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Turns out it was only 50% my fault.  The new tag watching sidebar was missing an element that passed the test mentioned above, meaning questions for teams users weren't getting the class `tagged-ignored-hidden`.  It wouldn't have mattered though, because Teams users are now also getting the "unified theme" where a different rule clobbered `display: none` with `display: flex`.  I upped the priority with `display: none !important`.